# opengl 2.1 and textures

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to show a texture(yes it is a pot) with opengl 2.1 and glsl 120, but i'm not sure on how to do it, all i can get is a black quad, i've been following this tutorials: [A Textured Cube](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/), [OpenGl - Textures](https://open.gl/textures) and what i have understood is that i need to:

1. Specify the texture coordinates to attach to each vertex(in my case are 6 vertices, a cube without indexing)
2. Load the texture and bind it in a texture unit(default is 0)
3. call glDrawArrays
4. Inside the shaders i need to:
5. Receive the texture coords in an attribute in the vertex shader and pass it to the fragment shader through a varying variable
6. In the fragment shader use a sampler object to sample a pixel, in the position specified by the varying variable, from the texture.

Is it all correct?

Here is how i create the texture VBO and load the texture:

```
void Application::onStart(){
unsigned int format;
SDL_Surface* img;

float quadCoords[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f};

const float texCoords[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 
        1.0f, 0.0f, 
        1.0f, 1.0f, 
        1.0f, 1.0f, 
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f};

//shader loading omitted ...
sprogram.bind(); // call glUseProgram(programId)
//set the sampler value to 0 -> use texture unit 0
sprogram.loadValue(sprogram.getUniformLocation(SAMPLER), 0);

//quad
glGenBuffers(1, &quadBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*18, quadCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//texture
glGenBuffers(1, &textureBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*12, texCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//load texture
img = IMG_Load("resources/images/crate.jpg");

if(img == nullptr)
    throw std::runtime_error(SDL_GetError());

glGenTextures(1, &this->texture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img->w, img->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->pixels);

SDL_FreeSurface(img);
}
```

rendering phase:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(COORDS);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(COORDS, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEX_COORDS);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(TEX_COORDS, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

//draw the vertices
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 coord;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec2 UV;

void main(){    
    gl_Position = vec4(coord.x, coord.y, coord.z, 1.0);
    UV = texCoord;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D tex;
varying vec2 UV;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor.rgb = texture2D(tex, UV).rgb;
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

I know that the tutorials use `out` instead of `varying` so i tried to "convert" the code, also there is this tutorial: [Simple Texture - LightHouse](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-12-tutorial/simple-texture/) that explain the `gl_MultiTexCoord0` attribute and `gl_TexCoord` array wich are built in, but this is almost the same thing i'm doing. I want to know if 'm doing it all right and if not, i would like to know how to show a simple 2d texture in the screen with opengl 2.1 and glsl 120

Comment: Where's the part where you bind the texture to the sampler?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: @immibis, before binding my texture i call `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)` wich is the default sampler in the shaders

Comment: Not sure if this is your entire code, but you don't seem to set the texture filters. Default minification filters are with mipmapping, and your texture is not mipmap-complete (hence sampling won't work).

Comment: @dehass, That was it, i added the `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);` and `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);` and it is working now, i was really trying to do a minimalist texture renderer test that i decided to take this function calls off. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a particular reason to use opengl 2.1 with glsl version 1.2 ? If not stick to the openGl 3.0 because its easier to understand imho.
My guess is you have 2 big problems :

First of all getting a black quad: If its size occupies your hole app then its the background color. That means it doesn't draw anything at all .
I think(by testing this) OpenGL has a default program which will activate and even if you have already set a vertex array/buffer object on the gpu.It should render as a white quad in your window... So that might be ur 1st problem . I dont know if opengl 2.1 has vertex buffer arrays but opengl 3.0 has and you should definetly make use of that!

Second : you don't use your shader program in the rendering phase; 
Call this function before drawing your quad:

`glUseProgram(myProgram); // The myProgram variable is your compiled shader program`

If by any chance you would like me to explain how to draw your quad using OpegGL 3.0 ++ let me know :) ...It is not far from what you already wrote in your code .

Comment: Yes i have a reason to use ogl 2.1 and glsl 1.2, my computer is very old(from 2010) and i really can't buy a new one right now, the quad is being drawn correctly, it does not occupies all the screen, i also tested with a triangle. I'm really sorry for this but i forgot to show where i bind my gl program wich is in the `//... shader loading` section that i ommited because of my gl wrapper classes, i'll change it now.

Comment: Here is some useful website that shows all the functions available in ogl by version: http://docs.gl/gl2/glUseProgram

Comment: If your quad draws to the screen then your texture UVs might not get to the shader . There is another way :  vbo = { v1.x, v1.y, v1.z, uv1.x , uv1.y, v2.x, v2.y, v2.z, uv2.x , uv2.y, /* and so on*/ } basically vertices and uv data are  packed in the same vbo and when calling  glVertexAttribPointer(COORDS, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr); change 0 (the stride) to 3* sizeof(GLfloat)
glVertexAttribPointer(TEX_COORDS, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr); and here 0 to 2 * sizeof(GLfloat) // stride 
and nullptr to (GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(GLfloat))  //(the offset)